# arraylist implementation stop working after appending 32754 elements

Tags: arrays, c, arraylist

My arraylist implementation stop working after appending 32754 elements. I think it is very weird that this problem only occurs after appending so many elements and 32000 is still not too high to reach  I know I am not checking for NULL pointer and that my test program is a infinite loop. I am using a old version to reduce the code complexity.
output:

```
32752
32753
32754
zsh: segmentation fault  ./acl
```

array.c:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stddef.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

union arraylist_meta {
    double dummy_double;
    long double dummy_long_double;
    long long dummy_long_long;
        void *dummy_ptr;
        void (*dummy_func_ptr)(void);
        struct {
            size_t len;
            size_t cap;
        size_t sizeof_one_element;
        };
};

void* acl_arraylist_create(size_t array_size, size_t sizeof_one_element) {
    union arraylist_meta *arraylist_new = malloc(array_size * sizeof_one_element + sizeof*arraylist_new);
    arraylist_new->len = array_size;
    arraylist_new->cap = array_size;
    arraylist_new->sizeof_one_element = sizeof_one_element;
    return arraylist_new+1;
}

void* acl_arraylist_append(void *arraylist_void, void *element) {
    union arraylist_meta *arraylist = arraylist_void;
    --arraylist;
    if(arraylist->len == arraylist->cap) {
        arraylist->cap = arraylist->len + 10;
        arraylist = realloc(arraylist, arraylist->cap * arraylist->sizeof_one_element + sizeof *arraylist);
    }
    memcpy((char*)(arraylist + 1) + arraylist->sizeof_one_element * arraylist->len, element, arraylist->sizeof_one_element);
    ++arraylist->len;
    return arraylist+1;
}
```

array.h:

```
#ifndef array_h
#define array_h
#include <stddef.h>
void* acl_arraylist_create(size_t array_size, size_t sizeof_one_element);
void* acl_arraylist_append(void *arraylist_void, void *element_void);
#endif
```

a simple test programm:

```
#include <acl/array.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
int main() {
    int *num = acl_arraylist_create(0, sizeof *num);
    for(int i = 0;;++i) {
        num = acl_arraylist_append(num, &i);
        printf("%d\n", i);
    }
}
```

Edit:
I changed the of the executable a while ago. By reverting a few commits back my build script was using the old name again, but executed the executable with name. This means that the problem I describe above does not with code above. It only occurs when using the code below:
array.c:

```
#include <stddef.h> 
#include <stdlib.h> 
#include <string.h> 
#include <acl/array.h> 
size_t acl_arraylist_len(void *arraylist); 
void acl_arraylist_free(void *arraylist); 
static inline void* acl_arraylist_resize(union acl_arraylist_meta *arraylist, int64_t relativLen) { 
        size_t cap = arraylist->cap + relativLen; 
        arraylist = realloc(arraylist, cap * arraylist->sizeof_one_element + sizeof *arraylist); 
        if(arraylist != NULL) { 
                arraylist->cap = cap; 
        } 
        return arraylist; 
} 
void* acl_arraylist_create(size_t array_size, size_t sizeof_one_element) { 
        union acl_arraylist_meta *arraylist_new = malloc(array_size * sizeof_one_element + sizeof*arraylist_new); 
        if(arraylist_new == NULL) return NULL; 
        arraylist_new->len = array_size; 
        arraylist_new->cap = array_size; 
        arraylist_new->sizeof_one_element = sizeof_one_element; 
        return arraylist_new+1; 
} 
void* acl_arraylist_append(void *arraylist_void, void *element) { 
        void *element_append; 
        union acl_arraylist_meta *arraylist = acl_arraylist_append_ptr(arraylist_void, &element_append); 
        if(arraylist == NULL) return NULL; 
        --arraylist; 
        memcpy(element_append, element, arraylist->sizeof_one_element); 
        return arraylist + 1; 
} 
void* acl_arraylist_append_ptr(void *arraylist_void, void **append_element) { 
        union acl_arraylist_meta *arraylist = arraylist_void; 
        --arraylist; 
        if(arraylist->len == arraylist->cap) { 
                acl_arraylist_resize(arraylist, 10); 
                if(arraylist == NULL) return NULL; 
        } 
        *append_element = (char*)(arraylist + 1) + arraylist->sizeof_one_element * arraylist->len; 
        ++arraylist->len; 
        return arraylist + 1; 
} 
void* acl_arraylist_remove(void *arraylist_void, size_t index) { 
        union acl_arraylist_meta *arraylist = (union acl_arraylist_meta*)arraylist_void - 1; 
        char *arraylist_char = arraylist_void; 
        if(index != arraylist->len - 1) { 
                memcpy(arraylist_char + arraylist->sizeof_one_element * index, arraylist_char + arraylist->sizeof_one_element * (arraylist->len - 1), arraylist->sizeof_one_element); 
        } 
        --arraylist->len; 
        if(arraylist->len < arraylist->cap - 20) { 
                void* arraylistTmp = acl_arraylist_resize(arraylist, -10); 
                if(arraylistTmp != NULL) arraylist = arraylistTmp; 
        } 
        return arraylist + 1; 
}
```

array.h:

```
#ifndef _acl_array_h
#define _acl_array_h
#include <stddef.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
union acl_arraylist_meta {
    double dummy_double;
    long double dummy_long_double;
    long long dummy_long_long;
        void *dummy_ptr;
        void (*dummy_func_ptr)(void);
        struct {
            size_t len;
            size_t cap;
        size_t sizeof_one_element;
        };
};
inline size_t acl_arraylist_len(void *arraylist) {
    return ((union acl_arraylist_meta*)arraylist - 1)->len;
}
inline void acl_arraylist_free(void *arraylist) {
    free((union acl_arraylist_meta*)arraylist-1);
}
void* acl_arraylist_remove(void *arraylist_void, size_t index);
void* acl_arraylist_create(size_t array_size, size_t sizeof_one_element);
void* acl_arraylist_append(void *arraylist_void, void *element);
void* acl_arraylist_append_ptr(void *arraylist_void, void **append_element);
#endif
```

a simple test programm:

```
#include <acl/array.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(void)
{
    void *num = acl_arraylist_create(100, sizeof(int));
    for (int i = 0; i < 65536; ++i)
    {
        num = acl_arraylist_append(num, &i);
        printf("%d\n", i);
    }
}
```

Comment: Where is `num` defined? How is it initialized?

Comment: And you don't have *any* kind of error checking. Both `malloc` *and* `realloc` can fail, and return `NULL`  pointers. Now think about what happens when you try to dereference that `NULL` pointer. Furthermore, even if `realloc` fails and return a `NULL` pointer, the *original* pointer will still be valid. By reassigning back to the original pointer with the call, you loose that original pointer and have a memory leak.

Comment: It's worrying that your `array.c` source file does not include the header (`acl/array.h`) that declares the services that the source file defines.  It means there is no cross-checking.  The headers provide the glue that holds C programs together, providing cross-checking to ensure that the code using the services provided agrees with the code providing those services.  —— **Also**: Your sample program doesn't create a list — your code should not compile because `num` is not defined.

Comment: When resequence a bit, the code does compile cleanly.  When I added a call `void *num = acl_arraylist_create(100, sizeof(int));` and ran the code, I got to iteration 150 before the Mac OS library said: `acl23(54767,0x10d41b5c0) malloc: *** error for object 0x7f8c40c02bb0: pointer being realloc'd was not allocated` —
`acl23(54767,0x10d41b5c0) malloc: *** set a breakpoint in malloc_error_break to debug`.  If you've got Valgrind available to you, use it.

Comment: I think your code is playing with fire (and you're getting burnt) because you're trying to combine the `union arraylist_meta` structure and the array data, but when the whole lot is reallocated, you are not using the new value returned by `acl_arraylist_append()`.  Change the line in the loop to `new = acl_arraylist_append(num, &i);` and the code runs up to 65535 for me (I set the loop to `for (int i = 0; i < 65536; ++i)` rather than imposing no limit).

Comment: It isn't clear how the user of your array list is going to access elements of the array.  Presumably, you plan to have them convert the `void *` (`num` in the example) to an appropriate typed pointer (`int *array = num;`) and they can then index into the array.  It's also not clear how they determine the size of the array — what the maximum index is.

Comment: I fixed the example code and I have a length function that is not included here because it is not relevant to the problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's worrying that your `array.c` source file does not include the header (`acl/array.h`) that declares the services that the source file defines. It means there is no cross-checking. The headers provide the glue that holds C programs together, providing cross-checking to ensure that the code using the services provided agrees with the code providing those services.

Also: Your sample program doesn't create a list — your code should not compile because `num` is not defined.

When resequenced a bit, the code does compile cleanly. When I added a call:

```
void *num = acl_arraylist_create(100, sizeof(int));
```

before the loop in `main()` and ran the code (source code `acl23.c`, program `acl23`), I got to iteration 150 before the Mac OS library said:

```
acl23(54767,0x10d41b5c0) malloc: *** error for object 0x7f8c40c02bb0: pointer being realloc'd was not allocated
acl23(54767,0x10d41b5c0) malloc: *** set a breakpoint in malloc_error_break to debug.
```

If you've got Valgrind available to you, use it.

I think your code is playing with fire (and you're getting burnt) because you're trying to combine the `union arraylist_meta` structure and the array data.

However, the primary problem is that when the memory is reallocated, you are not using the new value returned by `acl_arraylist_append()`. Change the line in the loop to:

```
new = acl_arraylist_append(num, &i);
```

and the code runs up to 65535 for me.  I set the loop to stop then, rather than imposing no limit.

```
for (int i = 0; i < 65536; ++i).
```

It isn't clear how the user of your array list is going to access elements of the array. Presumably, you plan to have them convert the `void *` (`num` in the example) to an appropriate typed pointer (`int *array = num;`) and they can then index into the array. It's also not clear how they determine the size of the array — what the maximum index is.  You've also not provided a function to free the array.  The user can't do that — the pointer they have is not the one returned by one of the allocation functions (`malloc()`, `realloc()`, etc).  None of these are immediately critical; we can safely assume that they were omitted from the
MCVE ([Minimal, Complete, Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) — or MRE or whatever name SO now uses) you provided.

Here's my working code derived from yours — all in a single file.  The changes are actually quite minor.

```
/*array.h:*/
#ifndef array_h
#define array_h
#include <stddef.h>
void *acl_arraylist_create(size_t array_size, size_t sizeof_one_element);
void *acl_arraylist_append(void *arraylist_void, void *element_void);
#endif

/*array.c:*/
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stddef.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
/*#include <acl/array.h>*/

union arraylist_meta
{
    double dummy_double;
    long double dummy_long_double;
    long long dummy_long_long;
    void *dummy_ptr;
    void (*dummy_func_ptr)(void);
    struct
    {
        size_t len;
        size_t cap;
        size_t sizeof_one_element;
    };
};

void *acl_arraylist_create(size_t array_size, size_t sizeof_one_element)
{
    union arraylist_meta *arraylist_new = malloc(array_size * sizeof_one_element + sizeof *arraylist_new);
    arraylist_new->len = array_size;
    arraylist_new->cap = array_size;
    arraylist_new->sizeof_one_element = sizeof_one_element;
    return arraylist_new + 1;
}

void *acl_arraylist_append(void *arraylist_void, void *element)
{
    union arraylist_meta *arraylist = arraylist_void;
    --arraylist;
    if (arraylist->len == arraylist->cap)
    {
        arraylist->cap = arraylist->len + 10;
        arraylist = realloc(arraylist, arraylist->cap * arraylist->sizeof_one_element + sizeof *arraylist);
    }
    memcpy((char *)(arraylist + 1) + arraylist->sizeof_one_element * arraylist->len, element, arraylist->sizeof_one_element);
    ++arraylist->len;
    return arraylist + 1;
}

/*a simple test programm:*/

/*#include <acl/array.h>*/
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(void)
{
    void *num = acl_arraylist_create(100, sizeof(int));
    for (int i = 0; i < 65536; ++i)
    {
        num = acl_arraylist_append(num, &i);
        printf("%d\n", i);
    }
}
```

I'm not going to show the output; the numbers from 1 to 65535 are not exciting.

I distrust `void *` as the handle type for your array.  The user could provide any pointer of their choosing as a handle and there's no way to know that it's the wrong type of pointer.  Provide an **opaque type** instead; in the header, define:

```
typedef struct acl_arraylist acl_arraylist;
```

Then have the functions take and return an `acl_arraylist *`.  The client code doesn't need to know what's in it.  Your code in `array.c` might wrap the `union arraylist_meta` value into a structure:

```
struct acl_arraylist
{
    union arraylist_meta array;
};
```

You can then play in much the same way you did before.  But the user has to work to pass an arbitrary pointer to the functions — sufficiently hard that they won't get it wrong.

Comment: to convert the void* to typed pointer to access the elements is exactly what I planned.  And I do not return a pointer of special type because this. I have functions for freeing and to get length. If I use your modified code I still get the same error.

Comment: I assume you did not change array.c because I did not copy it.

Comment: Apart from automatic reformatting, I don't think I changed the implementation in `array.c`.   I see what you mean about not changing the return type.  I'm surprised you are having problems with the revised code.  I recommend copying and pasting my whole example into a new self-contained file and compiling and executing that.  Then you can compare my code with your code.  But I didn't need to change much.  Test with Valgrind if you can.

Comment: I changed the name of the executable a few months ago. I check out a old commit with the old executable name. So I was running the false executable all the time xd. Oh man haha. I guess the problem doesn't even exists with the old version.But the feedback was very helpfull. I will edit my question to the new code above

Comment: Such things can happen — it's infuriating when you find that you've been conned.  Making a backup of what's broken (just in case it is important after all) and then rebuilding from scratch can be good — `make clean` and then `make all` if the rules are present and thorough.

Comment: Don't change the question to match the answer.  If you must update the question, simply add a note explaining what happened.

Answer (score 0):

The new pointer returned from `acl_arraylist_resize` is ignored in `acl_arraylist_append_ptr`.
modified code:

```
void* acl_arraylist_append_ptr(void *arraylist_void, void **append_element) {
    union acl_arraylist_meta *arraylist = arraylist_void;
    --arraylist;
    if(arraylist->len == arraylist->cap) {
        arraylist = acl_arraylist_resize(arraylist, 10);// this line was modified
        if(arraylist == NULL) return NULL;
    }
    *append_element = (char*)(arraylist + 1) + arraylist->sizeof_one_element * arraylist->len;
    ++arraylist->len;
    return arraylist + 1;
}
```